# Yii Model - MANY_MANY relations - do I still need a HAS_MANY?

Tags: yii

I am defining the many to many relationship between two objects (ModelA & ModelB for this example) through three tables/active record models in the following way:

ModelA --< ModelA_B >-- ModelB

Where ModelA_B contains a foreign key field to both ModelA and ModelB. So in the code for ModelA I have have added to the **relations()** function:

```
'modelbs' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'ModelB', 'tbl_modelb(modela_id,modelb_id)'),
```

My question is do I still need the HAS_MANY relationship that was generated by Gii to represent the relation to the linking table ModelA_B or is this declared implicitly by the MANY_MANY above?

```
'modelabs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ModelA_B', 'ModelA_Id'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `MANY_MANY` relation, you don't need to define another `HAS_MANY` relation for the `ModelA_B` table.

But you could also use the `through` feature, which will replace the `MANY_MANY` relation at some point (probably in Yii 2.0 if i remember right). In this case you would define 2 relations:

```
'mobelabs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ModelA_B', 'ModelA_Id'),
'modelbs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Model_B', 'ModelB_Id', 'through'=>'modelabs'),
```

Now you have access to both related records: the `ModelA_B` via `$modelA->modelabs` and the `ModelB` via the `$modelA->modelbs`.

Comment: Great answer, not sure about migrating to 'through' just yet as I have some third party extensions that it may interfere with.